# Why am I receiving this NullReferenceException error when testing for null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am receiving an error on the following line of code:  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
if (Session["AutoCompleteCustomersPhone"] != null)
```

The full block of code:

```
if (Session["AutoCompleteCustomersPhone"] != null)
    earchCustomerPhone = true;
else
{
    searchCustomerPhone =
        bool.Parse(Session["AutoCompleteCustomersPhone"].ToString());
}
```

Why, in a test for null, am I receiving this error?

[image]

Comment: Most likely, `Session` itself is `null`.

Comment: Where exactly does this code run? It may give us a clue as to why Session is null...

Comment: Is this in an ASMX web service, or WCF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Because sessionn object itself null**

i think you are making use of webservice that is the reason why the session is null*

**check this aricle if you are using session in webservice :** [**Using Session State in a Web Service**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35119/Using-Session-State-in-a-Web-Service)

Comment: You are indeed correct. Its a web service. I guess my next question would be is it possible to use Session in a web service? Thats for a different topic though. Thanks.

Comment: @Kevin - check the article link pasted by me resolve your issu

Answer (score 10):

Your `if` statement is the wrong way around. You are trying to use the value if it *is* null.

Change this:

```
if (Session["AutoCompleteCustomersPhone"] != null)
```

to this:

```
if (Session["AutoCompleteCustomersPhone"] == null)
```

I'd fix that first, and see if that solves the problem.

The exception coming from that *specific* line might be either because:

- The `Session` variable is null - you can verify this in the debugger.
- Your compiled code differs from the source code you are using to debug. Try cleaning and rebuilding.

Comment: +1 Good spot, but that wouldn't cause the exception on this particular line.

Comment: @greg84 Yeah in the else, but curious why the exception is reported in the `if`, hence I amended "on this particular line".

Comment: This is why writing if statements using "not" logic gets people into trouble. @Mark is correct, your if statement is backwards.

Comment: I originally tried this, and it failed. So I switched to != and when that didn't work, I posted the question. Thanks though!

Comment: @Kevin Switching it would only then make your code logically incorrect. When the exception occurs you can review the values in each variable that is currently in scope. If any of them are null, the value will state null. Check your Session object.

Comment: Your initial suggestion was/is correct.  Session is null, because this code is in a web service.  Sorry for not mentioning it. I didn't realize it would cause an issue with the code.